# how to format date YYYYMMDDmmhhssuuu

Tags: javascript, date

I have a 'timestamp' value `20200513134950000` and the format should be YYYYMMDDmmhhssuuu.
I can not wrap my head around how to properly format it. I have tried date-fns library and native Date format, but with no luck.
Any ideas?

Comment: Euh, don't you have the correct format already?  2020-05-13 13:49:50.000 ? Or what exactly is the problem? Turning that number back into a Date object?

Comment: Yeah, parse it to date object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [DayJS](https://day.js.org/en/).
Its a lightweight library and allows you to specify `custom parse format` for parsing the dates.

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
var customParseFormat = require('dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat')
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)
console.log(dayjs('20200513134950000', 'YYYYMMDDmmhhssuuu'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all the relevant parts from the number with a simple regexp or even by counting numbers. Then the only caveat is that months are zero-based, but apart from that, you can just use the standard Date() constructor.

```js
const timestamp = 20200513134950000;

const UTC_mask = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})/;

const [
  year,
  month,
  day,
  hour,
  min,
  sec,
  ms
] = timestamp.toString().match( UTC_mask ).slice( 1 );
      
const datetime = new Date( year, parseInt( month, 10 ) - 1, day, hour, min, sec, ms );

console.log( datetime );
```

Comment: The month can be just `month - 1`, the `-` operator coerces the string to number for you. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Without any library you can just get the parts and pass them to the Date constructor:

```js
let ts = '20200513134950000';
let [c,y,m,d,H,M,S] = ts.match(/\d\d/g);
console.log(new Date(c+y,--m,d,H,M,S).toString());
```